# Autohotkey script with combination of keystroke

Tags: autohotkey

Hi I tried doing the script but i don't know why its not executing?
Can you guys give some autohotkey tester so i can test and clearly see if its working or not.

```
    #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
   ; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
      ;#KeyHistory
    ;#InstallKeyHook
     SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
   SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

   Numpad0::
   Send, ^c  
   Sleep 300
   Send, !{Tab}
   Sleep 300
   Send, ^v  
   Sleep 300
   Send, {F9} 
   Sleep 300
   Send, {Tab 4}  
   Sleep 300
   Send, {ENTER} 
   Sleep 300
   Send, {Tab 4}  
   Sleep 300
   Send, {ENTER}  
   Sleep 300
   Send, ^s  
   Sleep 300
   Send, !{Tab}
   Sleep 300 
   Send, {DOWN}
   Sleep 300
   return
```

Comment: have you attempted it yet? Look at the "Send" function in AHK. Try something, then update this question. We wont just write the code for you.

Comment: See [Sending Keystrokes](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s3) in the tutorial.

Comment: Try adding Sleep (e.g to wait 0.3 sec. add `Sleep 300`) between the Send commands (Send works too fast). Instead of AltTab and (maybe after Send, {F9}) you can use `WinWait`, `WinActivate` and `WinWaitActive` before sending commands to the active window. To repeat  a keystroke use e.g. `Send, {TAB 4}`.

Comment: @user3419297 iedited my code can you check it? i put alttab on that because im shifting from excel to other open application..

Comment: Without knowing details about what are you trying to do is difficult to say.